# Why isn't WC_Product::get_id() equal to WC_Product::$id, whilst the code implies it has to be?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Given the `$product` is an instance of [WC_Product_Variation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Variation.html), this code:

```php
$product_id_1 = $product->id;
$product_id_2 = $product->get_id();

var_dump($product_id_1, $product_id_2);
```

...will output different values, in my case:

```php
int(12465)
int(12466)
```

Why would it be this way, when the definition of the `get_id()` function is:

```php
public function get_id() {
    return $this->id;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `$product->id;`,you won't read the propertie 'id' from the object, because its protectd. It invokes the Magic __get method for backwards compatibility, defined in [WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-legacy-abstract-wc-legacy-product.html#source-view.66). And then the following happens:

```
$value = $this->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $this->get_parent_id() : $this->get_id();
```

In case of 'variation', it retrieves the 'parent_id'.

It is a good practise to use setter and getter, properties should not be accessed directly.